# Batching push to Windows notification server

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

We have managed to create a service which will push notifications to the Windows Nofification Server (WNS) and that works fine.

We only need to push notifications to WNS once a day. Hence, I would like to know if there is any way that we could batch the Uris into one call that which we can send to WNS rather than making as many calls as there are clients registered. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Architecture is build that way. You have to make as many calls as there are Clients. But what is the matter? A request is cheap on perfomance and traffic.

Comment: Hi, I've just started on a greenfield project and I was trying to get as many things set up correctly as possible. However, if that's the architecture, then so be it. Thank you for your answer.